# Send message to a client when an HTTP method not supported

Tags: rest, spring-mvc, tomcat, http-status-codes

I've created a REST controller the can handle, as usual, GET, POST, PUT and DELETE HTTP requests using Spring MVC. The web server is Tomcat 8.
If a send request, for instance, with HEAD method, the response is an error page from Tomcat with message

```
HTTP Status 501 - Method LINK is not is not implemented by this servlet for this URI
```

I have such exception handler:

```
@ResponseBody
@ExceptionHandler(Throwable.class)
public ResponseEntity<?> exceptionHandler() {

    Error error = createError("error_message.unforeseen_error");

    return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).body(error);
}
```

But it doesn't catch any error in this case.

Is there a way to send back a message wrapped in JSON object as a response instead of this Tomcat page?

Comment: Can you show your `web.xml` file?

Comment: The problem is solved. Thank you for the time spent!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that SpringMVC does not find any method for HEAD in your controller, so it does not use it and your @ExceptionHandler is not used. It would be used for exception arising inside the controller. Extract from Spring Frameword Reference : *You use the @ExceptionHandler method annotation within a controller to specify which method is invoked when an exception of a specific type is thrown **during the execution of controller methods*** (emphasis mine).

To process exception outside of any controller, you must register a `HandlerExceptionResolver` bean that will replace the `DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver` provided by default by Spring MVC. You could either directly put the Json String in the response and return null from `resolve` method (my prefered way), or put the elements in a model and use a view to format the Json.